# AngularJS: $emit method sending duplicate data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, broadcast

In my AngularJS app, I have three controllers. One is the main controller and the other two are siblings.

I have `Sibling control 1` to emit data to `Main control`, which broadcasts the data, which `sibling control 2` then picks up.

*Sibling control 1*

```
$scope.selectedPatentFx;

$scope.$watch('selectedPatentFx', function(newValue, oldValue){ 
    if($scope.selectedPatentFx) {
       $scope.$emit('calculateFx', {patentfx: newValue});       
    }
})
```

*Main control*

```
$scope.$on('calculateFx', function(event, obj){
    $scope.$broadcast('calculateFxBroadcast', {fx: obj})
});
```

*Sibling control 2*

```
$scope.$on('calculateFxBroadcast', function(event, obj){
   //handle obj
})
```

The issue is that the data is being sent twice. However it doesn't cause any errors (as of yet).

***Question***

Why is the data being emitted/broadcasted twice?

Comment: try adding a condition to verify newValue & oldValue are different then only emit ex: simply `if(newValue && newValue != oldValue)`.

Comment: `selectedPatentFx watch` might be executing twice.

Comment: Still invoking twice. @RahulSharma, possibly, the selectedPatentFx value changes within a carousel function :/

Comment: you should try which @supercool has suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using events (`$broadcast`) here. You can do it by using a service which shares the data. I created an abstract example which delivers you the basic handling.

**> Share data via service between controllers - [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h96cyesy/)**

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="setData()">
        Set data
      </button>
  <h1>
    Controller1
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <p>
    {{data.getContactInfo()}}
  </p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyOtherCtrl">
  <br><br>
  <h1>
    Controller2
  </h1>
  <hr> {{data.getContactInfo()}}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

  $scope.data = myService;

  $scope.setData = function() {
    myService.setContactInfo('Hello World');
  }
});

myApp.controller('MyOtherCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.data = myService;
});


myApp.service('myService', function() {
    this.contactInfo = '';

    this.setContactInfo = function (data) {
        this.contactInfo = data;
    }

    this.getContactInfo = function () {
        return this.contactInfo;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll have a go at this approach

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Has helped me out a hell of a lot. If only I took this approach months ago