# $broadcast is not working in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, broadcast, angularjs-events

I am using two controllers. When changes happen in one controllers it should get changed immediately in the other controller. I am using the $broadcast event to achive this.

My code:

My First controller

```
app.controller('configurationCtrl', function($scope, $http,Notification,$rootScope,$cookies) {
$scope.awssubmit=function(){
  $scope.page_loader=true
  $http.post("/insert_config_details",$scope.userdata).then(function(List){
   if(List){
   $scope.page_loader=false;
   $cookies.put("bucket",$scope.userdata.bucket_name)
   $scope.$broadcast('eventEmitedName', 'Some data');
   Notification.success('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <strong>AWS Configuration details updated successfully.</strong>');
}
  else{
  $scope.page_loader=false;
  Notification.error('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <strong>Error!!! Please try again later.</strong>');
  }
  $scope.awssave = false;
  $scope.awstext=true;
  })
 } 
});
```

My Second Controller:

```
app.controller('SidemenuController', function($scope, $http,$location,BucketService) 
 {

      $scope.$on('eventEmitedName', function (event, data) {
         console.log("Called"); //I am not getting this 
    value
        console.log(data); // 'Some data' // I am not getting this 
    value
      });
});
```

aws_submit() is called from my view and everything seems to work fine. But in SidemenuController I am not getting any data. Is there any mistake in my code?

Update:

My view :

```
 <form id="awsform" method="post" name="awsform" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 four_module_config">
                      <div class="account_settings">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 heading_config" ng-hide="awssave">
                          <h4 class="sub_title col-sm-11" style="border-bottom:none">AWS S3 Configurations</h4>
                          <% if(valid_role[1]) { %>
                            <div class="action col-sm-1">
                              <span class="actico editrole" ng-click="editaws()">
                        <a href='javascript:void(0)' ></a>
                        </span>
                            </div>
                            <% } %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 heading_config" ng-show="awssave">
                          <h4 class="sub_title col-sm-9" style="border-bottom:none">AWS S3 Configurations</h4>
                          <div class="action col-sm-3 close_config">
                            <button  type="button" class="site_btn submit_btn save_config col-sm-2" id="submit" ng-show="awstest"
                              ng-click="verifyaws()">Test</button>
                            <button type="button" class="site_btn submit_btn save_config col-sm-2" id="submit" ng-show="submitawssave"
                              ng-click="awssubmit()">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="site_btn submit_btn save_config col-sm-2" id="submit" ng-click="closeaws()">Cancel</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ipfield  col-md-8 hint_txt_conf">
                          *Enter your AWS access Key, S3 Bucket name configured in your AWS Environment. Which is used to store your document in the
                          cloud.
                        </div>
                        <div class="ipfield first_ipfield">
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label for="name" class="usrlabel">AWS access key <span class="mandat">*</span></label>
                            <input type="password" ng-disabled="awstext" ng-model="userdata.key" required name="key" class="txt_box" id="key" placeholder="Enter AWS access key">
                            <span toggle="#key" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ipfield">
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label for="name" class="usrlabel">AWS Secret Key <span class="mandat">*</span></label>
                            <input type="password" ng-disabled="awstext" ng-model="userdata.secretkey" required name="secretkey" class="txt_box" id="secretkey" placeholder="Enter AWS Secret Key">
                            <span toggle="#secretkey" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ipfield">
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label for="name" class="usrlabel">AWS Region Code <span class="mandat">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" ng-disabled="awstext" ng-model="userdata.region" required name="region" class="txt_box" id="region" placeholder="Enter AWS Region Code">

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ipfield">
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label for="name" class="usrlabel">AWS Bucket Name <span class="mandat">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" ng-disabled="awstext" ng-model="userdata.bucket_name" required name="bucket_name" class="txt_box" id="bucket"
                              placeholder="Enter  AWS Bucket Name">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: Could you please add `HTML` code?

Comment: Updated kindly check

Comment: Not just button code. I need `ng-controller` directive code as well.

Comment: Check adding `console.log()` above `$scope.$broadcast()` line. Will get to know it is getting called or not.

Comment: Did `ng-controller` directive is present? If yes then Try @Ved solution, this could be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send data from one controller to another controller using $`brodcast` than use `$rootscope.$broadcast`

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('eventEmitedName', 'Some data');
```

Second Controller

```
app.controller('SidemenuController', function($scope, $http,$location,BucketService) {
    $scope.$on('eventEmitedName', function (event, data) {
        console.log("Called");
        console.log(data); // 'Some data'
        $scope.bucket = data;
    });
});
```

> Note: Do not use `$rootscope.$on` as listener  because $rootscope
>   listener are not destroyed . Instead it will create listeners stack

Comment: Thank you its working Perfect . Am getting the value if i used for $scope.bucket = data,        Its not get updating in view

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call one controller event into another there are four methods available:

- `$rootScope.$broadcast()` if your controller are not in a parent / child relation.
- If your second controller (event fired here) is a parent you can use `$scope.$broadcast();`
- If your second controller (event fired here) is a child you can use `$scope.$emit();`
- The best way to solve this would be to **use a service** -> [Example of using a service to share data between controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148694/angularjs-emit-method-sending-duplicate-data/49149266#49149266).

**Note:** You need to destroy `$rootScope.$on()` listeners manually avoid stacking events. This [Difference between $rootScope.$on vs $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632318/difference-between-rootscope-on-vs-scope-on/43638652#43638652) and this  [Do you need to unbind $scope.$on in $scope $destroy event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247286/do-you-need-to-unbind-scope-on-in-scope-destroy-event/42247423#42247423) will help you understand the basics of using events.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="broadcast()">
    broadcast
  </button>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MySecondCtrl">
  {{ test }}
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.broadcast = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('test', 'testit');
  }
});

myApp.controller('MySecondCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  var registerScope = $rootScope.$on('test', function(test, args) {
    console.log(args);
    $scope.test = args;
  });

  // clean up, destroy event when controller get destroyed. 
  $scope.$on('$destroy', registerScope);
});
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/393k25t5/)**